# Unable to use libproc in a sandboxed OSX app for app store

Tags: c++, macos, appstore-sandbox

I have a C++ application that uses libproc to get a list of open applications. Works as expected when not sandboxed. However to deploy to app store, it must be sandboxed and when doing so, proc_listallpids (from libproc) no longer works. Anyway around this?

```
#include <libproc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void find_pids()
{
    pid_t pids[2048];
    int bytes = proc_listallpids(pids, sizeof(pids));
    int n_proc = bytes / sizeof(pids[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_proc; i++) {
        struct proc_bsdinfo proc;
        int st = proc_pidinfo(pids[i], PROC_PIDTBSDINFO, 0,
                              &proc, PROC_PIDTBSDINFO_SIZE);
        printf("%s\n", proc.pbi_name);
    }
}


int main()
{
    find_pids();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSWorkspace.runningApplications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1534059-runningapplications?language=objc) is the more Mac-specific way to get info about running applications (rather than just processes), it's possible that will work in a sandboxed app. But in general, sandboxed apps shouldn't be able to see each other.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way around this.

The purpose of the sandbox is to isolate your application from other processes running on the machine. It is doing its job correctly by preventing your application from viewing those processes.

Comment: agress with this